# How can I make Spring Framework 's @Cachable work with lastModified property of a File as key?

Tags: java, spring, ehcache

This is the code I have:

```
@Cacheable(value = "configurationCache", key = "#myFile.lastModified()")
private Object foo(File myFile) throws IOException {
    System.out.println(myFile.lastModified());
    try {
        Thread.sleep(6000);
    } catch (InterruptedException ignored) {

    }
    final Object foo = new SomeObjectFromFile(myFile);
    return foo;
}
```

I call this method twice passing file objects that have the same lastmodified value but caching does not work, the method will wait for 6 seconds.

Here is the output I am getting:

```
1456298573000
1456298573000
```

What am I doing wrong?

```
key = "#myFile.lastModified"
```

did not work either..

I am sure my configuration with ehcache is fine.

Comment: are you using aspectj-cacheable support? could you please post snippets from your configuration? changing your log-configuration to print debug output for the spring-cache packages may also help you find the cause

Comment: dependening on how often you invoke this method, lastModified()-invocations may hurt your performance, you should consider using a watchService as an alternative (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/notification.html)

Comment: and another note. isn't keying by lastModification-timestamp alone a little brittle a mechanism, what if two files had the same lastMod-timestamp. you should take the absolute-filename into account

Comment: @cproinger Yes you are right but it is ok in this case..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Juliens answer is probably the right one assuming you do not use aspectj. its not alone invoking a public method, but invoking a public method of an object where spring had the chance to wrap it's proxies around. So make sure you are injecting the service that you want to have enhanced with cacheable support.

For example

```
@Service
public SomeService {
    @Autowired
    private CacheEnhancedService css;

    public void doSomething() {
        css.getConfig(new File("./file"));
     }
}

@Service
public CacheEnhancedService {
    @Cacheable(value = "configurationCache", key = "#myFile.lastModified()")
    public Object getConfig(File myFile) {
        ...
     }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue lies with the fact that your method is private.

As mentioned in the [documentation of the Spring Framework](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/cache.html):

> Method visibility and cache annotations
>
> When using proxies, you should apply the cache annotations only to
> methods with public visibility. If you do annotate protected, private
> or package-visible methods with these annotations, no error is raised,
> but the annotated method does not exhibit the configured caching
> settings. Consider the use of AspectJ (see below) if you need to
> annotate non-public methods as it changes the bytecode itself.
>
> [...]
>
> In proxy mode (which is the default), only external method calls
> coming in through the proxy are intercepted. This means that
> self-invocation, in effect, a method within the target object calling
> another method of the target object, will not lead to an actual
> caching at runtime even if the invoked method is marked with
> @Cacheable - considering using the aspectj mode in this case. Also,
> the proxy must be fully initialized to provide the expected behaviour
> so you should not rely on this feature in your initialization code,
> i.e. @PostConstruct.

You should either switch to a public method and make and external call or user AspectJ.

Comment: Making the method public did not help, but thanks anyway.

Comment: Are you calling your method by an external method calls ? I guess not. You should probably switch to AspectJ